# Number of distinguishable ways to paint the sides regular n-gon using m colors

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics

I'm trying to derive a general formula for the number of distinguishable ways to paint the sides regular $n-$gon using $m$ colors.

Two rules:

We don't have to use all of the $m$ colors and we have to account for rotations.

My progress:

We have to divide whatever we end up getting by $n$ to account for rotations. But from there I can't see a good next step. I know how to solve say, a square with 2 colors, but when I take the same approach for $n$ sides and $m$ colors, I get lost in recursion and inclusion-exclusion.

Any takers?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside's_lemma is the standard tool here. I think you will find the prime factorisation of $n$ matters a lot.

Comment: This is the [number of $m$-ary necklaces of length $n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics)#Number_of_necklaces).

Comment: thanks guys. got it